# How convert string to byte and vise versa with khmer string?

Tags: string, unicode, arrays

I am using following code:

```
 String data = "យោងតាមឯកឧត្តមតាំង សាមឿនលេខាសម្តេចកិត្តិព្រឹទ្ធបណ្ឌិតប៊ុន រ៉ានីហ៊ុនសែនបានប្រាប់ក្រុមអ្នក";
                byte[] tempp = data.getBytes();
                String newString = tempp.toString();
```

and i get following output

```
[B@41f2ca10
```

Any one guide me how can i get same string back? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag with relevant programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert byte to string using you current encoding

```
String newString = new String(tempp);
```

Comment: which encoding i use here?

Comment: You can use constructor's overload String(byte[], string) to pass encoding's name, or just use platform default encoding as my code does. As long as you don't pass encoding to getBytes() method, use String(byte[]).

Answer (score 0):

Simple `toString()` function like following code is not working property. It will not display the original text but byte value.

```
String s = bytes.toString();
```

In order to convert `Byte` array into `String` format correctly, we have to explicitly create a String object and assign the Byte array to it.

```
String s = new String(bytes);
```

**Running code**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data = "យោងតាមឯកឧត្តមតាំង សាមឿនលេខាសម្តេចកិត្តិព្រឹទ្ធបណ្ឌិតប៊ុន រ៉ានីហ៊ុនសែនបានប្រាប់ក្រុមអ្នក";
        byte[] tempp = data.getBytes();
        String newString = new String(tempp);
        System.out.println(newString);
    }
```

**output**

យោងតាមឯកឧត្តមតាំង សាមឿនលេខាសម្តេចកិត្តិព្រឹទ្ធបណ្ឌិតប៊ុន រ៉ានីហ៊ុនសែនបានប្រាប់ក្រុមអ្នក